# PHP Mysql does not accept table name as variable

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, var

mysql does not recognize the name of my table in a variable in a function, what can it be?

My PHP Code:

```
$TableMaster = "table_name";
function recursiveDelete($id,$db,$table){
    $db_conn = $db;
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE Padre = '".$id."' ");
    if ($query->rowCount()>0) {
        while($current=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            recursiveDelete($current['id'],$db_conn);
        }
    }
    $db->exec("DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE id = '".$id."' ");
}
recursiveDelete($_POST['id'],$db,$TableMaster);
```

ERROR PHP LOG:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Father = '99'' at line 1' in
```

Note: But when I write the name of my mysql table directly in the statement there is no problem.

Whats happen?

Comment: can you show us a error part ?

Comment: You're not passing $table in `recursiveDelete()` when you do the call `recursiveDelete($current['id'],$db_conn);`

Comment: update my post. :)

Comment: @RenatoRamosPuma Well, you could try as a debug test `echo "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE Padre = '".$id."' " (optional . "<br>\n");` and that should be insightful.

Comment: @RenatoRamosPuma glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left out the `$table` argument when making the recursive call.

There's also no need for the `$db_conn` variable, you can just use `$db`.

```
function recursiveDelete($id,$db,$table){
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE Padre = '".$id."' ");
    if ($query->rowCount()>0) {
        while($current=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            recursiveDelete($current['id'],$db,$table);
        }
    }
    $db->exec("DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE id = '".$id."' ");
}
```

Comment: What I don't get is why doesn't it throw an error for not having enough arguments?

Comment: Master you have found the solution, thank you very much. :)

Comment: @Chipster PHP is permissive about incorrect argument number. I prints a warning, but doesn't throw an error.